# Inductive step for the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: induction

Let $F_{n}$ be a Fibonacci sequence given by
$$F_{n}=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } n=0 \\ 
1 & \text{ if } n=1 \\ 
F_{n-1}+F_{n-2} & \text{ if } n\geq 2.
\end{cases}$$
I was asked to prove that $(3/2)^{n-1}\leq F_{n}$ holds for all $n\geq 6$. I fail to satisfy the Inductive Step. Assume that it holds for some $n=k$ and I wish to show that it is true for $n=k+1$. We have
$$\left ( \frac{3}{2} \right )^{k}=\frac{3}{2}\left ( \frac{3}{2} \right )^{k-1}\leq \frac{3}{2}F_{k}\overset{?}<F_{k+1}.$$
Is there another correct way to show it?

Comment: You need to assume it holds for some $k$ and $k-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:  As remarked by @ThomasAndrews, it is absolutely essential that the induction start somewhere.  In particular, in this case one must check that the desired inequality holds for $F_6$ and $F_7$.  This is not difficult (by straight computation), but it has to be done.  Worth remarking that the inequality is false below $6$, but happily true for $F_6=8>(\frac 32)^5\sim7.59$. (just to be thorough , $F_7$ passes easily as $F_7=13>(\frac 32)^6\sim 11.39$).

From the recursion (and the induction hypothesis) we have $$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}≥\left(\frac 32\right)^{n-2}+\left(\frac 32\right)^{n-3}=\left(\frac 32\right)^{n-3}\left(\frac 32+1\right)$$

All that remains is for you to verify that $$\left(\frac 32+1\right)≥\left(\frac 32\right)^2$$

Comment: The induction hypothesis, as the OP stated it, is not enough. Worth pointing out that you are assuming the *two* previous values have the property. (In particular, then, this means you have to prove the cases $n=6$ and $n=7$ separately.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews True, of course.  I had trusted that the OP had covered that.  I'll amend the solution accodingly.

Comment: I have proven the induction start, only for $n=6$ and not above since I was too lazy. But is it an good idea to use the strong induction in this case? I like your idea.

Comment: @AjmalW  The recursion goes deeper than one level, so I'd use induction beyond one level.  So, I would check $F_7$ as well (just takes a second).  You never need more than two levels so I guess it is somewhere in between strong induction and the ordinary form.